# Tkiz: draw a dependency graph of attribute grammars

Tags: tkz-graph

I am trying to draw this and I am not sure if it's doable in Tkiz because it's so complicated and I am failing.

The idea of this graph is the triangle at the top is the beginning of at least one "augmented dependency graph" and at the bottom is a child "augmented dependency graph". The squares or circles are at least two inherited (left bottom square) and synthesized (right top square) attributes. The values go from the inherited attribute to children and come back up to the synthesized attribute. Then I added a "summary" edge (blue) to say we don't need to go to children and come back up because we can summarize the child's dependency using a summery edge.

[image]

A simpler version if the above is not possible:
[image]

[My failed attempt](https://www.overleaf.com/7161477956cgrkppyrytrc):

Result from code below: [image: codes result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains, 
                positioning}
                
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.node-families}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                positioning
                }
                
\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style={decoration={markings,% switch on markings
                        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4
                        with {\arrow[thick]{Straight Barb}}
                        },
            postaction={decorate}
            }
                        ]
\draw[fill=gray!10] (0,0.0) -- ++ (10, 0) -- ++ (-5,5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!20, semitransparent] 
                    (0,2) coordinate (A) node[]{} 
                            -- ++ (2,-1) -- ++ (-4,0) -- cycle;


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, not clear to me how the final result should look like. // Suggestion: Think and code simpler. Ignore fine tuning like semitransparent areas for the moment. Fokus on creating and placing basic elements. Refine from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, thinking simple.

Tried mimicking your first sketch. Don't know, if that's what you are after. Lots of room left for tweaking and fine tuning.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for shape or arrow tips
                
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [arr/.style={> = {Stealth}}]% replace standard arrow tip
    % ~~~ coordinates for the triangles ~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,2.5);
    
    \coordinate (c) at (1,1.5);
    \coordinate (a) at (-.2,-1);
    \coordinate (b) at (2.5, -1);
    
    % ~~~ triangles ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \draw (a) -- (c) -- (b);
    
    % ~~~ rectangles ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [draw] (R) at (.8,.4) {};
    \node [draw] (S) at (1.12,.6) {};
    
    % ~~~ blue arrow ~~~~~~
    %     with nicer arrow tip
    %     using nodes anchors
    %     bending the blue line
    
    \draw [blue, ->, arr] 
        (R.south) to [out=290, in=250] (S.south);
    
    % ~~~ red line ~~~~~~~~~~
    %     use rounded corners, radius 7mm
    %     draw a path, which runs through the rectangles
    
    \draw [red, ->, arr, rounded corners=7mm] 
        (1,2) -- (R) -- (.3,-.5) -- (1.7,-.5) -- (S) -- ((1.5, 1.5);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I asked a follow up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685238/tkiz-draw-a-dependency-graph-of-attribute-grammars-follow-up