# TikZ: draw a dependency graph of attribute grammars

Tags: tkz-graph

This is a follow-up to [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685214/tkiz-draw-a-dependency-graph-of-attribute-grammars). I made some progress but it's not finished. I build upon [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685214/tkiz-draw-a-dependency-graph-of-attribute-grammars/685218#685218)

What I currently have:

[image]

What I want it to be:

1. are these two lines parallel to each other?
2. add two arrows tips in the middle
3. add question mark below the blue arrow

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    calc, chains, 
                    positioning}
                    
    \usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
    \usetikzlibrary{ext.node-families}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    decorations.markings,
                    positioning
                    }
                    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [arr/.style={> = {Stealth}}]% replace standard arrow tip
        % ~~~ coordinates for the triangles ~~~~~~~~~~
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (1.2,2.5);
        \coordinate (D) at (3.2,2.5);
            
        \coordinate (c) at (1,1.5);
        \coordinate (a) at (-0.2,-1);
        \coordinate (b) at (2.5, -1);

        % ~~~ triangles ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B) -- (D);
        \draw (a) -- (c) -- (b);

        % ~~~ rectangles ~~~~~~~~~~
        \node [draw] (R) at (0.8,.4) {};
            \node [draw, anchor=south west] (S) at(R.north east) {};

        % ~~~ blue arrow ~~~~~~
        %     with a nicer arrow tip
        %     using nodes anchors
        %     bending the blue line

        \draw [blue, ->, arr] 
        (R.south) to [out=-90, in=-90, looseness=2.75] (S.south);

        % ~~~ red line ~~~~~~~~~~
        %     use rounded corners, radius 7mm
        %     draw a path, which runs through the rectangles

        \draw [red, ->, arr, rounded corners=7mm] 
        (1,2) -- (R) -- (0.3,-1) -- (1.7,-1) -- (S) -- ((1.2, 2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, your „progress“ is using my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685218/245790 without any citation … Not very nice. Also, you didn‘t clarify your question there.

Comment: Can you please modify the question to cite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To make the lines parallel, use polar coordinates `(θ:r)`. Relative coordinates help also, for example, `\draw (A) -- ++(θ:r);`.
- Arrow tips in the middle should be added as a `marking` decoration using `postaction=decorate`
- Question mark can be a node positioned relative to the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
%                calc, chains, 
%                positioning}
                
%\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
%\usetikzlibrary{ext.node-families}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                %positioning
                }
                
\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [arr/.style={> = {Stealth}}, arrmark/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}, postaction=decorate}]% replace standard arrow tip
    % ~~~ coordinates for the triangles ~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (60:3);
    %\coordinate (D) at (3.2,2.5);
        
    %\coordinate (c) at (1,1.5);
    \coordinate (a) at (-0.2,-1);
    %\coordinate (b) at (2.5, -1);

    % ~~~ triangles ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B) -- ++(120:3)coordinate(D);
    \draw (a) -- ++(60:3)coordinate(b) -- ++(-60:3)coordinate(c);

    % ~~~ rectangles ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [draw] (R) at (1,.4) {};
        \node [draw, anchor=south west] (S) at(R.north east) {};

    % ~~~ blue arrow ~~~~~~
    %     with a nicer arrow tip
    %     using nodes anchors
    %     bending the blue line

    \draw [blue, ->, arr] 
    (R.south) to [out=-90, in=-90, looseness=2.75]node[below right=-3pt]{\scriptsize?} (S.south);

    % ~~~ red line ~~~~~~~~~~
    %     use rounded corners, radius 7mm
    %     draw a path, which runs through the rectangles
    
    \draw[red] (R) -- ++(80:1.2);
    \draw [red, ->, arr, rounded corners=7mm, arrmark=.15, arrmark=.6] 
    (R) -- (0.3,-1) -- (1.7,-1) -- (S) -- ++(80:1.2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you make sure there is an arrow at that two locations? can we add more add arrows

Comment: @Node.JS: The `arrmark` style defined at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` accepts an argument that represents the percentage of the length along the path. So  adding `arrmark=.15` will add the arrow 15% along the way. You can add as many as you want, but add them in order (otherwise unintended things happen). Also, with the `stealth` arrows you may want to include the `bending` library if your arrows end up on the curved portion.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. When I add `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]`, arrows break

Comment: You need to add the `scale` option alongside the other options:`\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25, arr/.style=...`

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you!